# async/await - try ... catch inside $.when

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, try-catch

I'm working on a small project at work which requires multiple AJAX calls to various API endpoints. The first three require data from one another successively, and the last three can be ran independently as they do not have any relationship to the first three.

This is my first major foray into async/await, and actually utilizing promises for their intended purpose, and I've come to a point of confusion as to how to handle any exceptions. We're using Vue.js as our front-end framework and consuming JSON responses.

I call the functions containing my requests with this function:

```
fetchAllData: async function() {
    await this.getList()
    await this.getSecondListRelatedToFirst()
    await this.getThirdListRelatedToFirstAndSecond()
    this.getDateRange()
    getConversions()
    getVolumes()
}
```

The how the requests are running right now:

```
this.getList()
|------------> this.getSecondListRelatedToFirst()
              |----------> this.getThirdListRelatedToFirstAndSecond()
              |------> this.getDateRange()
              |------> getConversions()
              |------> getVolumes()
```

`this.getList()` runs, then `this.getSecondListRelatedToFirst()` runs when `this.getList()` resolves, and the last four run when `this.getSecondListRelatedToFirst()` resolves.

The requests are all structured fairly similar to this:

```
getList: function () {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/api/endpoint',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            param_one  : param_one,
            param_two  : param_two,
            param_three: param_three,
            ...
        }
    })
    .then(function(data, status, xhr) {
         let temp = _.map(data, function (d) {
             return {
                 // map some data here         
             }
         }.bind(this));

    }, function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error(errorThrown);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
         console.log.bind(error)
})
```

The basic idea is once the response comes back from the server, I manipulate the data into something more easily consumable by Vue, and move along with rendering the page.

Coming full circle, to the first function, `fetchAllData`, which is called in the `mounted` lifecycle property like so:

```
$.when( this.fetchAllData() )
 .then( function() {
    // do some other stuff
 })
 .fail(
      console.log.bind(console);
 );
```

And this is where my question lies. Considering I'm doing error catching at the AJAX level (with the then, catch blocks), do I need to do error catching here as well? And if so, how would I achieve that in the `$.when` block? Or is the final `fail` statement sufficient at this point in execution?

This question is probably a case of reading way too many use cases and not enough experience with Vue.js and async/await, I just need some clarification on best practices for this type of scenario. Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

```
var response = await promisedFunction().catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
// response will be undefined if the promise is rejected
```

Maybe it will answer your question.